# Energy Momentum Tensor for a complex scalar field in GR

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I want to find the EM tensor for a charged scalar field $\Psi $ with mass $m$ in curved space time. I am considering the following action:

$\tag{1} S = -\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{-g}\text{ }d^4x\text{ }(g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi + m^2\Psi^*\Psi)$

While varying the action with respect to the metric, I first vary the $\sqrt{-g}$ factor using the result $\delta \sqrt{-g} = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g_{ab}\delta g^{ab}$. Then, I vary the Lagrangian, or rather the gradient term in this case. Doing so gives me:

$\tag{2} \delta S = -\frac{1}{2}\int (\delta \sqrt{-g}) d^4x\text{ }(g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi + m^2\Psi^*\Psi) + -\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{-g} \text{ }d^4x\text{ } (\delta g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi ) $

This gives,

$\tag{3} \delta S = -\frac{1}{2}\int (-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g_{ij}\delta g^{ij}) d^4x\text{ }(g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi + m^2\Psi^*\Psi) + -\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{-g} \text{ }d^4x\text{ } (\delta g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi) $

$\tag{} \delta S = \int \sqrt{-g}\text{ } d^4x \text{ } \delta g^{ij}[\frac{1}{4}g_{ij}(g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi + m^2\Psi^*\Psi) -\frac{1}{2}\text{ } (\partial_i\Psi^* \partial_j\Psi)] $

where I have changed the indices on the last term to group terms. This gives me an energy momentum tensor of the form,

$\tag{4} T_{ij} = \frac{1}{4}g_{ij}(g^{ab}\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi + m^2\Psi^*\Psi) -\frac{1}{2}\text{ } (\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi)$

My confusion with this is the following. This isn't symmetric, and I'm aware that the EM tensor must be symmetric. I am also aware that if I am obtaining this via a Noether's theorem application, then I could possibly add terms to make this symmetric. But from my understanding by directly varying the action with respect to the metric I should get a symmetric tensor which in this case will be the energy momentum tensor, because I am varying the matter action (just as varying the gravitational action gives the symmetric Einstein tensor and a boundary term). Therefore, I think instead of the last term, $(\partial_a\Psi^* \partial_b\Psi)$ I should have the symmetrisation of that term $(\partial_{(a}\Psi^* \partial_{b)}\Psi)$.

Even if my hunch is wrong, a text I am following, gives the EM tensor for a different but for a massless scalar field as the following:

$\tag{5} T_{ij} = (\partial_{(i}\Psi \partial_{j)}\Psi^*) - \frac{1}{2}g_{ij}|\partial_b\Psi \partial^b \Psi|$

If equation (4) had the symmetrised version of the last term, then setting $m=0$ would give me equation (5) which I presume is correct. But I do not understand how I am to get the symmetric form of that term in equation (4) since I am not getting it while varying the action as is normally done. I could very well be making a mistake while varying the action, and if so I'd like to know.

I'm just starting to learn this stuff so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that $\delta g^{ab}A_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}(\delta g^{ab}+\delta g^{ba})A_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\delta g^{ab}(A_{ab}+A_{ba})=\delta g^{ab}A_{(ab)}$.

Comment: Can you explain how $\delta g^{ab} = \frac{1}{2}(\delta g^{ab} + \delta g^{ba})$. Just because $g^{ab}$ is a symmetric tensor does not guarantee that $\delta g^{ab}$ would be one right? If I understand correctly, $\delta g^{ab}$ isn't a tensor at all?

Comment: When you vary the metric you deform it into a new metric.

Comment: Suppose I have an infinitesimal transformation $x^a \to x^a + \epsilon^a$ where $\epsilon^a$ is infinitesimal. Then, I can show that $\delta g^{ab} = \nabla^a\epsilon^a + \nabla^b\epsilon^b$. However, $\delta g_{ab} = -(\nabla_a\epsilon_a + \nabla_b\epsilon_b) \neq g_{ai}g_{bj}\delta g^{ij}$. So how is it a tensor?

Comment: $0=\delta(\delta_a^b)=\delta(g_{ac}g^{cb})=\delta g_{ac}g^{cb}+g_{ac}\delta g^{cb}\Rightarrow \delta g_{ab} = -g_{ac}g_{ad}\delta g^{cd}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your equation (3) just note that the skew-part within the bracket does not contribute to the EoM (i.e. any skew part acting on $\delta g^{a b}$ will vanish as $\delta g^{a b}$ is symmetric). So that that stage in your derivation you really should symmetrise the field equations.

Comment: Do you mean in the second term? If so, I have the same confusion as I have commented above. I am unsure how $\delta g^{ab}$ is a tensor, let alone a symmetric one at that.

Comment: Do you understand how the usual variations work, e.g. for the derivation of the EFE? $\delta g^{ab}$ *is* a symmetric tensorial object, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63904/when-a-variation-of-a-tensor-is-not-a-tensor

Comment: Thank you! This was my confusion!